# Camel SFTP can't establish connection

Tags: apache-camel

I have the SFTP server up in one docker container available at localhost:2222 with user user/pass
Trying to establish connection in other one via camel 2.22.0 route like

```
  from("sftp:user@localhost:2222/sftp/in?password=pass"))
   .log("${file:name}");
```

But cannot connect because of

```
  Error auto creating directory:/sftp/in due Cannot connect to sftp://user@localhost:2222. This exception is ignored.

org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot connect to sftp://pms@localhost:2222
at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.connect(SftpOperations.java:144)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileConsumer.connectIfNecessary(RemoteFileConsumer.java:233)

Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:394)
```

Got that after moving from camel 2.18.2 to camel 2.22.0.
Is it possible to fix?

Comment: I believe it should be like this `from("sftp://user@localhsot:2222/sftp/in?password=pass");` and check you have permissions to connect for this user

Comment: I use Filezilla to check this connection with this user and it was ok.'//' didn't work for me

Comment: Maybe you can try different Camel versions between 2.18.2 and 2.22.0 to see which version was first started giving you that problem - that helps to pinpoint a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have also had this issue and resolved it by adding `camel-ftp` dependency:

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-ftp</artifactId>
    <version>3.16.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Please check dependency version that works for you here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-ftp

Answer (score 0):

We upgraded from camel 2.20.0 to camel 2.22.0 during development. After upgrading we could not reach camel from another server. Same problem, Connection Refused. We downgraded back to 2.20.0 and things started working again